# How to assign a value to a cell in dataframe A based on a value in dataframe B, conditional on values of two other columns in B?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm really amateur-level with both python and pandas, but I'm trying to solve an issue for work that's stumping me.

I have two dataframes, let's call them dfA and dfB:

```
dfA:

     project_id    Category     Initiative

     10              
     20
     30
     40
```

```
dfB:

     project_id     field_id     value  
     10             100          lorem
     10             200          lorem1
     10             300          lorem2

     20             200          ipsum
     20             300          ipsum1
     20             500          ipsum2
```

Let's say I know "Category" from dfA correlates to field_id "100" from dfB, and "Initiative" correlates to field_id "200".

I need to look through dfB and for a given project_id/field_id combination, take the corresponding value in the "value" column and place it in the correct cell in dfA.

The result would look like this:

```
dfA:

     project_id    Category     Initiative

     10            lorem        lorem1
     20                         ipsum
     30
     40
```

Bonus difficulty: not every project in dfA exists in dfB, and not every field_id is used in every project_id.

I hope I've explained this well enough; I feel like there must be a relatively simple way to handle this that I'm missing.

Comment: Can't you simply merge both dataframes by using the in common column in both dataframes (project_id)?

Comment: There are multiple field_ids and corresponding values for each project_id though; with merging like this, how would I tell it which value goes in which column in dfA based on field_id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this although it's not very elegant, there must be a better way. I had to use try/except because of the cases where the project Id is not available in the dfB. I put NaN values for the missing ones but you can easily put empty strings.

```py
def get_value(row):
    try:
        res = dfB[(dfB['field_id'] == 100) & (dfB['project_id'] == row['project_id'])]['value'].iloc[0]
    except:
        res = np.nan
    row['Categorie'] = res
    try:
        res = dfB[(dfB['field_id'] == 200) & (dfB['project_id'] == row['project_id'])]['value'].iloc[0]
    except:
        res = np.nan
    row['Initiative'] = res
    return row

dfA = dfA.apply(get_value, axis=1)
```

**EDIT**: as mentioned in comment, this is not very flexible as some values are hardcoded but you can easily change that with something like the below. This way, if the field_id change or you need to add/remove a column, just update the dictionary.

```py
columns_field = {"Category": 100, "Initiative": 200}

def get_value(row):
    for key, value in columns_fields.items():
        try:
            res = dfB[(dfB['field_id'] == value) & (dfB['project_id'] == row['project_id'])]['value'].iloc[0]
        except:
            res = np.nan
        row[key] = res
    return row

dfA = dfA.apply(get_value, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you, I’ll give this a shot tomorrow and let you know how it goes! I don’t particularly care about elegant as long as it works.

Comment: This worked like a charm! I do have to hard-code the field_id values this way, but there are only maybe a dozen of them and this is a one-time thing so I'm happy to do it this way. I'm going to use this as a jumping-off point to expand my python knowledge, thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked! I hardcoded the values as there was only 2 in the dummy data you gave so it was fast. For a dozen, I would use a dictionnary. See my edited answer to see if I understood correctly what you need.